# how to iterate over txt file and store lines in variables c++

Tags: c++

I am looking for an easier way to get lines from a txt and store them in variables in c++.
In my txt file, a group of 3 lines represents 1 idea
An example of my txt file is the following: ( contains one idea)

*John Smith*

*cars, beaches, swimming*

*My name is john and i am a teacher*

here is my following code that stores each line in a vector

```
vector <string> inputText;
    string name, prop, keyword, cont;
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    file.open("input.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
       inputText.push_back(line);
    }

    file.close();
    name = inputText[0];
    keyword = inputText[1];
    cont = inputText[2];

    idea.setID();
    idea.setProposer(name);
    idea.setKeywords(keyword);
    idea.setContent(cont);
    newIdea.push_back(idea);

}
```

I am seeking a more efficient to store the lines in variables because i would like to have multiple ideas. using multiple ideas in my current code will result in an extremely long and inefficient code.
which idea from my txt file will use up 3 lines.
My question is, is there an efficient way to store multiple ideas from a txt file in variables without having to use the index.

EDIT: this is what i mean by long and inefficient code
for example say my txt file contains the following

*John Smith*

*cars, beaches, swimming*

*My name is john and i am a teacher*

*John apples*

*dogs, cats, swimming*

*My name is john and i am a tradsman*

*John loin*

*cars, cleaning, zoo*

*My name is john and i am a fisher*

than in my code i would need the following

```
idea.setProproser(inputText[0];
idea.setKeyword(inputText[1]);
idea.setContent(inputText[2]);
newIDea.push_back(idea);

idea.setProproser(inputText[4];
idea.setKeyword(inputText[5]);
idea.setContent(inputText[6]);
newIDea.push_back(idea);
```

then if i have say 10 ideas in the file i would need to repeat it a lot of times.

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: @idclev463035818 thats what i did, i used a vector to store the lines from txt file. but i want to know if there is an easier way to assign the contents of the vector to a string variable without having to go through each index

Comment: Just use a vector. Your string variables (`name`, `keyword`, and `cont`) are redundant. For example, you can just do `idea.setProposer(inputText[0])`.

Comment: sorry, I meant use a `std::vector<Idea>` but it seems you are also doing that already. I dont understand why multiple ideas will lead to "an extremely long and inefficient code". Your loop should populate the vector of `Idea`s and you dont really need the vector of strings

Comment: I wrote an anwer, but please next time post a [mcve]. I had to make some assumptions on code you did not include in the question

Comment: i have updated my post to show what i meant by inefficient and long code

Comment: yeah got it and added a PS on the answer. The thing is: You also didnt write one line of code for each line you read from the file, but you used a loop. When you want to traverse the vector of strings again you do the same: you write a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the vector of strings if you populate the vector of `Idea`s directly. With minimal changes on your code, you can change the while loop to

```
std::string name_line;
std::string keyword_line;
std::string content_line;
while (std::getline(file, name_line) && 
       std::getline(file,keyword_line) &&
       std::getline(file,content_line)) {
    Idea idea;
    idea.setID();
    idea.setProposer(name);
    idea.setKeywords(keyword);
    idea.setContent(cont);
    newIdea.push_back(idea);
}
```

However, you should use a constructor to construct an `Idea`. If you write a constructor that takes those three strings as parameters then the loop could look like this:

```
std::string name_line;
std::string keyword_line;
std::string content_line;
while (std::getline(file, name_line) && 
       std::getline(file,keyword_line) &&
       std::getline(file,content_line)) {
    newIdea.emplace_back(name_line,keyword_line,content_line);
}
```

PS: Even if you stay with the vector of strings, you do not need to write "an extremely long and inefficient code". Just as you use a loop to populate the vector of strings you could use a loop to construct the `Idea`s:

```
for (size_t i=0; i< inputText.size(); i+=3) {
    name = inputText[i];
    keyword = inputText[i+1];
    cont = inputText[i+2];
    // ...etc...
}
```

Always when you think you need to write the same code several times and the only difference is an index, the answer is a loop.

Comment: i appreciate the answer but what would happen if i had say 10 ideas in my text file?
because line 4 would be a empty line to denote a new idea

Comment: @elie1 then you don't read 3 but 4 lines for each entry in the file